# Lightbox Effect : Gray out body using only Javascript

Tags: javascript

**[ Learning Purpose ]**
I'm Trying to use only javascript for this..
any advices with the simplest way is very appreciate it.. 
I Have explained what I need to do in the button functions with comments..

P.S: I'm not sure if this is done using CSS.. so please guide me if it does.

**Seems Like I'm being misunderstood I'm look for this effect:
http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>#mydiv{height: 250px; width: 250px; background-color:#34f;}</style>
    <script>

        document.onreadystatechange = function()
        {
            if(document.readyState == "complete")
            {
                var div        =   document.getElementById("mydiv");    
                var mybutton   =   document.getElementById("mybutton");

                mybutton.onclick = function()
                {
                    // center div
                    // gray out the rest 

                };

                document.onclick = function()
                {
                    // remove gray out effect to the page 
                };

            }
        } 

    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="mydiv"></div>
<button id="mybutton"></button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Create a `<div>` which has _fixed position_ at _top, left, right and bottom_ of `0` and a _background_ of a semi-transparent black `rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75)`, then append this to `document.body`. To reverse, just remove this element.

Comment: I'm trying to fade out (disabling it) the body while centering the div..

Answer (score 3):

HTML:

```
<div id="mydiv" style="display:none"></div>
```

CSS:

```
#mydiv
{
    background-color: white;
    filter:alpha(opacity=50); /* IE */
    opacity: 0.5; /* Safari, Opera */
    -moz-opacity:0.50; /* FireFox */
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    z-index: 20;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:center;
    position:absolute;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
mybutton.onclick = function()
{
    document.getElementById("mydiv").style.display = "";
};

document.onclick = function()
{
    document.getElementById("mydiv").style.display = "none";
};
```

may be helps you.

Comment: this only removes the css of the div.. i'm trying to disable main content like the link i provided in my description